# Exoplayer dash streaming with widevine drm

Tags: exoplayer, drm, widevine

Hello I am developing an application where I will be available to play dash stream with widevine drm protection. I have read the sample of exoplayer but my need is different, I will on my website, and when click the dash url it will start playing the stream in exoplayer.  I have succeeded in doing first part for opening the exoplayer activity, however I dont know how I can run the drm protected stream on exoplayer.

I know the stream and drm licence url.

A simple code I am working on is attached below. Kindly help me with additional code for drmsessionmanager and etc. To run stream

here is my code which only supports mpd without drm:

```
public class exoplayer2 extends AppCompatActivity { // Variables
    private static final String VIDEO_URI = "http://url.mpd";

    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    private Handler mainHandler;
    private TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory;
    private TrackSelector trackSelector;
    private LoadControl loadControl;
    private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
    private MediaSource videoSource;
    private Uri uri;
    private String userAgent;
    private static final DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    // Activity onCreate
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exoplayer);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this,"SimpleDashExoPlayer");
        createPlayer();
        attachPlayerView();
        preparePlayer();
    }

    // Create TrackSelection Factory, Track Selector, Handler, Load Control, and ExoPlayer Instance
    public void createPlayer(){
        mainHandler = new Handler();
        videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,trackSelector,loadControl);
    }

    // Set player to SimpleExoPlayerView
    public void attachPlayerView(){
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    }

    // Build Data Source Factory, Dash Media Source, and Prepare player using videoSource
    public void preparePlayer(){
        uriParse();
        dataSourceFactory = buildDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter);
        videoSource = new DashMediaSource(uri,buildDataSourceFactory(null),new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory),mainHandler,null);
        player.prepare(videoSource);
    }

    // Parse VIDEO_URI and Save at uri variable
    public void uriParse(){
        uri = Uri.parse(VIDEO_URI);
    }

    // Build Data Source Factory using DefaultBandwidthMeter and HttpDataSource.Factory
    private DataSource.Factory buildDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter){
        return new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, bandwidthMeter, buildHttpDataSourceFactory(bandwidthMeter));
    }

    // Build Http Data Source Factory using DefaultBandwidthMeter
    private HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory(DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter){
        return new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, bandwidthMeter);
    }

    // Activity onStop, player must be release because of memory saving
    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        player.release();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To directly launch the PlayerActivity of the demo app an intent needs to be fired which passes the extras to declare the needed pieces for setting up the player including DRM parameters.

See the Developer Guide of ExoPlayer which [documents all the extras](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/demo-application.html#3-firing-an-intent).

This can be tested with adb:

```
adb shell am start -a com.google.android.exoplayer.demo.action.VIEW \
    -d https://yourdomain.com/sample.mpd  \
    -es drm_license_url [String] \
    -es drm_scheme widevine \
    ....
```

See the developer guide for [all options](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/demo-application.html#3-firing-an-intent).

See the source code of `initializePlayer` method of the PlayerActivity [how these intent extras are used to construct and setup the DrmSessionManager](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java#L267).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have already tried that and got one part in stuck:  buildDrmSessionManagerV18(
                      drmSchemeUuid, drmLicenseUrl, keyRequestPropertiesArray, multiSession);       I get error that buildDrmSessionManagerV18 the method cannot be resolved  my license url and drm scheme is same so I dont need and intent,  can you help me with the additional code to the above needed.

Comment: Have you found something ?.